# Is there a way I can shortcut an SQL OR clause with a AND clause?

Tags: sql

Is there a way to shorten an `SQL` statement below:

```
SELECT id, name FROM table_name
WHERE
status = 0 && price BETWEEN 20 AND 1000
&& city_id IN (7,8)
OR
status = 0 && price BETWEEN 20 AND 1000
&& country_id IN (4,14)
```

Comment: Use parenthesis?

Comment: Yes. You have `status = 0` in common, and also `price BETWEEN 20 AND 1000`.

Comment: BTW, which dbms are you using? ANSI SQL has `AND`, not `&&` for AND.

Comment: You mean the storage engine? InnoDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls try:

```
SELECT id, name FROM table_name
WHERE
status = 0 && price BETWEEN 20 AND 1000
&& (city_id IN (7,8) OR country_id IN (4,14))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
SELECT id, name FROM table_name
WHERE status = 0 and price BETWEEN 20 AND 1000 and 
(city_id IN (7,8,) or country_id IN (4,14))
```

Comment: You missed country_id .

Answer (score 1):

Here's your query.

```
select id, name from table_name
where
    status = 0 and price between 20 and 1000
and (
        city_id IN (7,8)
        or  
        country_id IN (4,14)
    )
```

Comment: You mean the storage engine? InnoDB